# s4 classes exported by default if presence of an initialize method

Tags: r, package, r-s4

I thought classes needed an exportClass directive in NAMESPACE to be exported,

but

Classes defined in a package  but not exported are nevertheless exported if there is an initialize method for the class in the code base.

that is to say I can create an instance of the class event though I exported nothing.

so

```
setClass("example", slots = c( title = "string"))
setClass("example2", slots = c( title = "string"))
```

and

```
setMethod("initialize","example, function(.Object, title) {
 .Object@title <- title
 . Object
})
```

in the package R directory and NAMESPACE present but with no export directives in it,

results in the possibility to create an instance of the class

```
library(example_package)
new("example") # ok
new("example2") # fails
```

I guess this is because initialize is a generics that is already defined

but does it mean you cannot prevent class instantiation by the user of the package if there is an initialize method for the class ?

or maybe put the initialize inside the setClass instruction ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think your second block of code has a couple of typos in it (unmatched `"` and a space in `. Object`. Are these just transcription errors or are they in the original code?